# Установка JDK для IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, java

Как скачать с oracle 32-bit JDK,только есть 86 и 64?И установить в саму программу IntelliJ IDEA?Прошу помощи я глупый,только учусь.

Comment: Может быть не `84 и 62`, а `86 и 64`?

Comment: Попробуйте скачать 86 - потом поделитесь впечатлениями.

Comment: Спасибо друзья я все понимаю но как установить?Может первым JDK а потом программу?Или как?

Comment: при создании проекта в idea, она попросит путь до папки с JDK (поле Project SDK). Туда указали и все.

Comment: Все верно, сначала устанавливаете JDK, а после IntelliJ IDE

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно скачать x86 - это и есть 32-bit.